# java.io.Serializable to Seq Scala

Tags: scala, serializable, case-class

I have a case match statement that provides the following output. I'm trying to convert this into a sequence instead. Can you please help me with this?

```
java.io.Serializable = List(TableInfo(X,XX,List(aa@aa.com, bb@bb.com)), 
TableInfo(Y,YY,List(aa@aa.com, bb@bb.com)))
```

[Code]:

```
scala.util.Either[Exception,List[TableInfo]] = 
Right(List(TableInfo(X,XX,List(aa@aa.com, bb@bb.com)), 
TableInfo(Y,YY,List(aa@aa.com, bb@bb.com))))

result match {
  case Left(s) => s
  case Right(i) => i
}
```

Complete Code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HT8wmYtsRF6DwzEkJYeygA

Comment: What code let you to that type?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I have updated the post with the same. Thank you.

Comment: The `match` block is picking the most common type between `Exception` and your list, and that happens to be `Serializable`. What sequence do you want if the value is a `Left`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, The left just throws an exception here. Underlying code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HT8wmYtsRF6DwzEkJYeygA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't throw any exceptions right now. Based on the comments, it sounds like your intention is to extract a `Right` or throw whatever's on the `Left`. In that case, all you're missing is the `throw` keyword.

```
result match {
  case Left(s) => throw s
  case Right(i) => i
}
```

`throw` breaks the normal flow of control, so it returns `Nothing`, which is the unique subtype of *all* types in Scala. Thus, the common types of `Nothing` and whatever `s` is, is simply the type of `s`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'm getting this error on trying this piece of code:  error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[TableInfo]
 required: Throwable
         case Right(i) => throw i

Comment: Whoops, I got the branches backwards. Your `Left` is your exception, I just flipped them accidentally

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked exactly as I intended it to.